# Jssor transition issue on large monitor

Tags: jssor

I've used the jssor slider on many different sites and recently had an issue come up on a couple different sites.  When the slides transition on a larger monitor the background images break up. Here is a link to one example (http://bit.ly/1DDYmrM) and the code I'm using is below.  Seems odd that this suddenly stopped working properly.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var _SlideshowTransitions = [
//Fade
    {$Duration: 700, $Opacity: 2, $Brother: { $Duration: 1000, $Opacity: 2} }
];
var _CaptionTransitions = [];
_CaptionTransitions["WAVE|B"] = { $Duration: 2800, $FlyDirection: 10, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.2, $Round: { $Left: 1.5} };

var options = {
    $ShowLoading: true,                                 //[Optional] Show loading screen or not default value is false
    $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
    $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
    $AutoPlayInterval: 7000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 10000
    $PauseOnHover: false,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slideshow is auto playing, default value is false

    $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                           //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
    $SlideDuration: 600,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 400
    $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
    //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
    //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
    $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
    $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
    $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
    $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, direction navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
    $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
    $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

    $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
        $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
        $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
        $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Required] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
        $ShowLink: 2,                                   //[Required] 0 After Slideshow, 2 Always
        $ContentMode: true                             //[Optional] Whether to involve whole html content of each slide to play slideshow, otherwise otherwise use the main image to play slideshow, default value is false
    },

    $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
        $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
        $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
        $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
        $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
    },

    $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable direction navigator or not
        $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create direction navigator instance
        $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
        $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1, default value is 1
    },

    $NavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
        $Class: $JssorNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
        $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
        $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both
        $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
        $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
        $SpacingX: 4,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
        $SpacingY: 4,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
        $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
    }
};
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);

function ScaleSlider() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if (windowWidth) {
        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(windowWidth, 100));
    }
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}

//Scale slider after document ready
ScaleSlider();

$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
```

});

Comment: What's your browser/version?

Comment: Chrome (Mac) Version 37.0.2062.124.

Comment: ... 27" monitor but my browser doesn't have to be full screen for the issue.

Comment: What do you mean 'stopped working properly'? How to reproduce?

Comment: Sorry, should've gave more detail.  While it's auto playing everything is fine. But, when you start clicking through with the directionals or dragging with the mouse part of the banner slides and part of it doesn't.  After a second it "catches up" and the remaining part of the banner dissapears.  Not sure if that makes sense or not.  Worse case scenario is I could hide the directional arrows at a larger screen size but there's no way to disable the drag feature at a larger browser size, correct?

Comment: To disable drag, please set $DragOrientation to 0. Also, you can try to set $HWA to false.

Comment: @jssor - I'd like to leave the drag option on, particularly for mobile.  Is there a way to shut it off if the window is greater than 1350px?  This seems to be the point where the slider no longer functions correctly.  If you drag or use the directions when the browser is greater than 1350px that is where the images start to break up.  Are you able to reproduce this?

Comment: $DragOrientation: window.screen.availWidth > 1350 ? 0 : 1

Comment: @jssor - I bought the slider files a while back and just downloaded the latest version and rebuilt the slider using those.  that solved my problem.  Just an fyi in case you get this question again.  Thanks for your help.